# Bulk export using BCP on Azure

Tags: sql, azure, bcp, bulk, xp-cmdshell

Within sql server, in a scheduled job, I was using the below command to create a csv file and upload it in a directory.

```
EXEC('EXEC xp_cmdshell ''bcp dbo.sales out "f:\db\salesbackUp\29July2022.csv" -T -c -t"," -C ACP -r\n -S"ICT-SQL02\ICTEPIC"''');
```

Now, I migrated to azure database ...
Is there any solution which will help me run the similar command, so that I can upload the csv file the either to azure storage or any where directly within the sql command. So that I can create the same scheduled job in azure job database.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approach to execute this but the best you can do by using **Azure Data Factory**.

> Azure Data Factory is a fully managed, serverless data integration service.

There are two methods:

1. Using `copy activity` you can move the data from Azure SQL database to Blob storage. Refer [Tutorial: Copy data from a SQL Server database to Azure Blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-hybrid-copy-powershell)
2. You can copy multiple tables in bulk using Powershell in Azure Data Factory. Refer [Copy multiple tables in bulk by using Azure Data Factory using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-bulk-copy)

Comment: Actually, I was getting data from various tables with in a proc and the save it in the form of a csv file. All that process was done within sql server. Now after migrating, I dont know how to do the same step in azure

Comment: yes I agree with you @UtkashPal, I came to conclusion that we have to use azure data factory